# How to remove "Reports" & "Tools" from the Contact, Account, & Opportunity homepages?

Tags: opportunity, page-layout, account, contact

Attempting to remove the "Reports" & "Tools" items from the homepages of Contact, Account, & Opportunity - is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are open for writing Code then here is one alternative.

1. Create a VF page and list all contact give link to standard edit/ new screen (same like existing list page)
2. Add tab for this VF page
3. Remove existing Contact tab from UI

Repeat above steps for all other objects.

This needs development efforts but you will be able to control everything non the list view page.

Comment: So far, unable to find any issues with this suggestion, other than as you say the dev-time, so I've selected your answer as the answer. If you're able to provide any pointers on how to get started on this solution, that would be great; if you wanted to post a question, answer it, then link to it as a comment, I'd be happy to upvote both the question and answer. Thanks!

Comment: **RELATED:** [How to recreate Contact, Account, & Opportunity homepages with Visualforce pages?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/36833/7651)

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there's any proper way to do this. One very hacky solution would be to add a side bar component that's available on all pages that hides appropriate elements with javascript, with jQuery it'd look something like:

```
$jq('div.toolsContent').toggle();
```

.. but that would hide that div for all pages so you'd need to check the URL etc. too. In short, I think you're better off leaving it as is.

Comment: Thanks, so the reports are removed via the permission sets, but are still displaying on those pages with links that result in permission errors, so doesn't make much sense for them to be there. Does that sound correct that should still be there? If that's not correct, guess I should post a different question.

Comment: I've never really looked at those components in detail... Sounds like a potential bug that the links don't get removed. Might be worth asking on success.salesforce.com

Comment: The links we see are always somewhat stupid. If user generally speaking has the right to Edit `CustomObject__c` (Profile + Permission sets) the SF will blindly list the "Edit" link on list views, related lists etc. Only when you click one of these you might face an "Insufficient privileges" b****slap caused by sharing rules for example. Which I think sucks but I understand it might be too costly to test access rights to every single record if there's a chance you won't click it at all...