# How to push a Visualforce page from a sandbox to production?

Tags: visualforce, sandbox, developer-console, production

Very possible that I am going about this completely wrong, but attempting to [deploy this code](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36833/how-to-recreate-contact-account-opportunity-homepages-with-visualforce-pages/36855?noredirect=1#36855) from a sandbox to production; attempted to do dev on production, via the dev-console, and got this error 'Can't alter metadata in an active org'; clearly that was a bad idea.

What is the best way to get started with pushing from non-production to production?

If it matters, appears that I was able to create a Visualforce page using the code, save, and preview it - and the sandbox is a developer pro sandbox type.

Comment: You can create and edit VF pages in a production org. Why not just use a change set? If you do not have access to change set then you can use tools like ANT, MavensMate, Eclipse, ect to deploy changes to production

Comment: @Eric: Thanks, possible I there's a misunderstanding, but on production, I got the error mentioned above when I attempted to preview the page dev-console; didn't get the error in the sandbox. Never used change sets. And yes, I'm aware their are tools, but I've never used them, and trying to stick to a "all web" solution; meaning I only used the dev-console to create/preview the code, not the Force-IDE. If using the IDE & deployment tools is really required, then that's fine, though other than using the IDE to download all the project files as a semi-backup, I have not used it at all.

Comment: Have you tried other means of deploying, though? Is it just straight VF or do you have Apex, too?

Comment: @MikeChale: When you say other means of deploying, not sure what exactly you mean, I don't even know a means of deploying.

Comment: @blunders - Not sure what you are trying to do BUT. If you goto Setup -> Develop -> Pages, click new, give it a name and save it. Then replace everything after salesforce.com/ in your address bar with apex/PAGENAME it will display fine. I do not get what you mean by preview in Dev console. Easiest way it to create the page directly in production using the UI (if there is no code associated with it) If you have code, create it in the sandbox and deploy using change sets. Link to change set doc: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_qs_deploy.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do BUT.

If you goto Setup -> Develop -> Pages, 
click new, 
give it a name and 
save it.

Then replace everything after salesforce.com/ in your address bar with apex/PAGENAME it will display fine.

I do not get what you mean by preview in Dev console. Easiest way it to create the page directly in production using the UI (if there is no code associated with it) If you have code, create it in the sandbox and deploy using change sets. Link to change set doc:

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_qs_deploy.htm

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly the help I needed, that being, how to create a new page; meaning it worked. Again, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, the 'best' way to get started is using the ide/eclipse plugin.

While you can us change sets or ANT and be successful, the learning curve for the IDE is only moderate (improvement over ANT imho) and gives added benefits of testing package deployments for success before you transmit the changes, local history comparison, server synchronization, old code history package, etc... (again jmho).

Noted that this goes against your comment of "'all web' solution," but from my perspective the long term benefits of the IDE is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you you for your thoughts, and get that the Force-IDE is the best dev-env, but in this case, this was [the answer I needed](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/36878/7651).