# How to remove “Reports” & “Tools” from the Contact, Account, & Opportunity homepages? Question on previous post

Tags: opportunity, account, page-layout, contact, list-view

I just joined so I don't have access to comment on the link below.  I created custom Contact and Opportunity home pages to get rid of the reports, links and Recently Viewed list.  It works fine in the full version, but it is screwed up in mobile.  At first, it wouldn't display at all, so I hid the header in the VF page.  Now it displays in Salesforce1, but it shows a browser version of the page, and the New buttons don't work.  Has anyone run into this, and if so, how did you fix it?

[How to remove "Reports" & "Tools" from the Contact, Account, & Opportunity homepages?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36777/how-to-remove-reports-tools-from-the-contact-account-opportunity-homep/36782#36782?newreg=013681ef192245199803d72157f6bbe0)